# In CoffeeScript, how do I get a value from an object based on another value matching a variable?

Tags: coffeescript, slack, hubot

I'm working on a bot for my team's Slack and so far my searches have come up empty. I'm retrieving a JSON object from an API, and it is returning fine. What I'm trying to do is get the value of the property of an element of the object based on if another property matches a variable being passed in to the function. In more detail, I'm trying to retrieve the `characterId` based on the `classHash`. I'm trying this, but it's not working. It results in characterId being undefined.

```
if data.characters[0].characterBase.classHash is classHash
  characterId = data.characters[0].characterBase.characterId
else if data.characters[1].characterBase.classHash is classHash
  characterId = data.characters[1].characterBase.characterId
else if data.characters[2].characterBase.classHash is classHash
  characterId = data.characters[2].characterBase.characterId
```

The JSON object is as follows:

```
"characters": [
                {
                    "characterBase": {
                        "membershipId": "4611686018451933949",
                        "membershipType": 2,
                        "characterId": "2305843009322984539",
                        "dateLastPlayed": "2016-07-31T02:53:56Z",
                        "minutesPlayedThisSession": "130",
                        "minutesPlayedTotal": "40010",
                        "powerLevel": 335,
                        "raceHash": 3887404748,
                        "genderHash": 3111576190,
                        "classHash": 2271682572}
                },
                {
                    "characterBase": {
                        "membershipId": "4611686018451933949",
                        "membershipType": 2,
                        "characterId": "2305843009340115467",
                        "dateLastPlayed": "2016-06-22T00:28:46Z",
                        "minutesPlayedThisSession": "108",
                        "minutesPlayedTotal": "11113",
                        "powerLevel": 333,
                        "raceHash": 2803282938,
                        "genderHash": 2204441813,
                        "classHash": 671679327}
                },
                {
                    "characterBase": {
                        "membershipId": "4611686018451933949",
                        "membershipType": 2,
                        "characterId": "2305843009327058547",
                        "dateLastPlayed": "2016-06-12T23:30:01Z",
                        "minutesPlayedThisSession": "62",
                        "minutesPlayedTotal": "9831",
                        "powerLevel": 334,
                        "raceHash": 898834093,
                        "genderHash": 3111576190,
                        "classHash": 3655393761}
                 }
```

I am trying to get the `characterId` of `characters[].characterBase` where the `characters[].characterBase.classHash` equals the one passed in. Say I pass in `2271682572` as the `classHash`, I want to return the characterId that matches that `classHash`, in this case `2305843009322984539`

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you mean to key into `characterBase` based on the string *value* of the variable `classHash`, then you need to use the `[]` property accessor instead of `.` like so: `data.characters[0].characterBase[classHash]`. Otherwise, its not clear what your problem is.

Comment: That didn't work. I'll add part of the JSON object I'm dealing with.

Comment: Please explain a) what your code is doing and b) what you want it to do. Its not at all clear from the description in your question.

Comment: I've updated the question. Hopefully it adds more clarity...I'm having a difficult time figuring out the wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `characterID`s are unique:

```
getCharIdByClassHash = (characters, classHash) ->
  characters.reduce(((result, char) ->
    result or # if we've already found the result, pass it thru
      (if char.characterBase.classHash is classHash
         char.characterBase.characterId
       else
         null)
  ), null)
```

You will either get back the characterId, or null if a match isn't found.

### Example:

```
getCharIdByClassHash(data.characters, 2271682572) # 2305843009322984539
```

### EDIT

this assumes your 'json' is NOT

```
"characters": [
                {
                    "characterBase": {
                        "membershipId": "4611686018451933949",
                        "membershipType": 2,
                        "characterId": "2305843009322984539",
                        "dateLastPlayed": "2016-07-31T02:53:56Z",
                        "minutesPlayedThisSession": "130",
                        "minutesPlayedTotal": "40010",
                        "powerLevel": 335,
                        "raceHash": 3887404748,
                        "genderHash": 3111576190,
                        "classHash": 2271682572,
                {
                    "characterBase": {
                        "membershipId": "4611686018451933949",
                        "membershipType": 2,
                        "characterId": "2305843009340115467",
                        "dateLastPlayed": "2016-06-22T00:28:46Z",
                        "minutesPlayedThisSession": "108",
                        "minutesPlayedTotal": "11113",
                        "powerLevel": 333,
                        "raceHash": 2803282938,
                        "genderHash": 2204441813,
                        "classHash": 671679327,
                {
                    "characterBase": {
```

Like you wrote it but is

```
"characters": [
                {
                    "characterBase": {
                        "membershipId": "4611686018451933949",
                        "membershipType": 2,
                        "characterId": "2305843009322984539",
                        "dateLastPlayed": "2016-07-31T02:53:56Z",
                        "minutesPlayedThisSession": "130",
                        "minutesPlayedTotal": "40010",
                        "powerLevel": 335,
                        "raceHash": 3887404748,
                        "genderHash": 3111576190,
                        "classHash": 2271682572
                    }
                }, {
                    "characterBase": {
                        "membershipId": "4611686018451933949",
                        "membershipType": 2,
                        "characterId": "2305843009340115467",
                        "dateLastPlayed": "2016-06-22T00:28:46Z",
                        "minutesPlayedThisSession": "108",
                        "minutesPlayedTotal": "11113",
                        "powerLevel": 333,
                        "raceHash": 2803282938,
                        "genderHash": 2204441813,
                        "classHash": 671679327
                    }
                }, {
                    "characterBase": {
```

Which is what I *think* you meant. [Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:getCharIdByClassHash%20%3D%20(characters%2C%20classHash)%20-%3E%0A%20%20characters.reduce(((result%2C%20char)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20result%20or%20%23%20if%20we've%20already%20found%20the%20result%2C%20pass%20it%20thru%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(if%20char.characterBase.classHash%20is%20classHash%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20char.characterBase.characterId%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20null)%0A%20%20)%2C%20null)%0A%0Adata%20%3D%0A%20%20%22characters%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22characterBase%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22membershipId%22%3A%20%224611686018451933949%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22membershipType%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22characterId%22%3A%20%222305843009322984539%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dateLastPlayed%22%3A%20%222016-07-31T02%3A53%3A56Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22minutesPlayedThisSession%22%3A%20%22130%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22minutesPlayedTotal%22%3A%20%2240010%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22powerLevel%22%3A%20335%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22raceHash%22%3A%203887404748%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22genderHash%22%3A%203111576190%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22classHash%22%3A%202271682572%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22characterBase%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22membershipId%22%3A%20%224611686018451933949%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22membershipType%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22characterId%22%3A%20%222305843009340115467%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dateLastPlayed%22%3A%20%222016-06-22T00%3A28%3A46Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22minutesPlayedThisSession%22%3A%20%22108%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22minutesPlayedTotal%22%3A%20%2211113%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22powerLevel%22%3A%20333%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22raceHash%22%3A%202803282938%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22genderHash%22%3A%202204441813%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22classHash%22%3A%20671679327%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%0Aalert(getCharIdByClassHash(data.characters%2C%20671679327))%3B).

Comment: @dkiefer I see the problem now, your array of objects is missing the closing braces.

Comment: It has the closing braces, I just shortened the actual object I'm getting back from the API (a lot of data).

Comment: @dkiefer well, then both Yury's and my solutions should work fine, unless the data is structured differently or the clashHash is actually a string instead of a number or something like that.

Comment: Added a demo. Alerts the characterId when run.

Comment: You're a genius. I didn't even think about the fact that I needed to convert it to a number, since it's part of a JSON string. Thank you so much!

Comment: @dkiefer no problem. Please accept if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is always one character with `classHash`. You can filter array, pop one and get its `character`

```
characterId = data
 .characters
 .filter (character) -> character.characterBase.classHash is classHash
 .pop()?.characterBase?.characterId
```

Or using array comprehesion

```
[characterId] = (id for {characterBase: {characterId: id, classHash: hash}} in data.characters when hash is classHash)
```

Not sure what your actuall data is but here is a [demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:data%20%3D%0A%20%20characters%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20characterBase%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20characterId%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20classHash%3A%20232989%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20characterBase%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20characterId%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20classHash%3A%208989898%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20characterBase%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20characterId%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20classHash%3A%2038783748%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%0AclassHash%20%3D%2038783748%0A%0A%5BcharacterId%5D%20%3D%20(id%20for%20%7BcharacterBase%3A%20%7BcharacterId%3A%20id%2C%20classHash%3A%20hash%7D%7D%20in%20data.characters%20when%20hash%20is%20classHash)%0A%0Aconsole.log%20%22character%20is%20%23%7BcharacterId%7D%20for%20hash%20%23%7BclassHash%7D%22%2C%20characterId).

Comment: Only reason I like `reduce` better here (and you mention it) is the failure case.

Comment: Comprehension example handle this case. `characterId` would be undefined if nothing matches. Or the first match if case of multiple characters having the same hash.

Comment: I tried both of these and neither worked. The first resulted in `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'characterBase' of undefined` and the second in `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. I'm extremely new to CoffeeScript, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I tried the first method after it was updated and now `characterId` is undefined

Comment: @YuryTarabanko pretty sure the problem is the array of objects, its malformed (at least with regards to the assumptions in our answers). See edit on my answer.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, because they both work for my purposes! Thank you for your help!